# What does these points mean in Naive Bayes?

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes

I have three concept related questions related to Naïve Bayes.

1. Naïve Bayes is robust to irrelevant features. What does this mean? Can anyone give an example how does the irrelevant features cancels out?
2. Decision trees suffer from fragmentation. What does this mean?
3. It is optimal if the independence assumption holds. Can anyone give an example of independence assumption not holding?

Regards,
Akshit Bhatia

Comment: what is the relation between this question and stackoverflow? i think you should ask it in other branches of stackexchange !

Comment: Ohh okay i didnt know about stackexchange.

Comment: there are so many, do you know which one is appropriate?